# Sommerfeld expansion for temperature dependent spectral function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, dirac-delta-distributions, analyticity

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I(\beta)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}\epsilon}{\pi}\frac{\rho(\epsilon,\beta)}{1+e^{\beta \epsilon}}
\end{align}
where $\rho(\epsilon,\beta)$ is a generic function of both $\epsilon$ and $\beta$.

When $\rho$ is sufficiently smooth and not a function of $\beta$, we can use the [Sommerfeld expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sommerfeld_expansion) to study the $\beta\to\infty$ (low temperature) behaviour 
\begin{align}
\label{eq2}
I(\beta)\underset{\beta\to\infty}{=}\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\text{d}\epsilon}{\pi} \rho(\epsilon)+\frac{\pi^2}{12\beta^2}\rho'(0)+O(\beta^{-4}).\tag{1}
\end{align}
This is sometimes explained as the mnemonic expansion of the Fermi-Dirac distribution
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+e^{\beta\epsilon}} \underset{\beta\to\infty}{=} \theta(-\epsilon)-\frac{\pi^2}{6\beta^2}\delta'(\epsilon)+O(\beta^{-4})\tag{2}
\end{align}

**Two questions**:

1. Can the conditions for Eq. (1) to hold be expressed in terms of exchange between integration and the series expansion in Eq. (2)? E.g. dominated convergence for the fermi-dirac distribution.
2. Can we follow a similar expansion of the Fermi-Dirac distribution when $\rho$ is also a function of $\beta$? In this case, what are the analytic properties $\rho$ must satisfy for this to hold? E.g. if $\rho$ is bounded (like for a spectral function).

Comment: One might be interested in the answers I got from math.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2351604/410094